# Не могу заблокировать прокрутку в нужный момент

Tags: javascript, html, прокрутка

Столкнулся с проблемой при блокировке скролла. При достижении определенной точки на странице скрипт должен блокировать возможность дальнейшей прокрутки. Попробовал реализовать так:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function{
    if (window.pageYOffset > 1300) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1300);
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }
});
```

Однако происходит такой эффект, будто метод `scrollTo` не работает (то-есть скролл заблокировался, до дальше определенной точки). Также пробовал проверять так `if (window.pageYOffset == 1300){}`, но таким образом слушатель не улавливает момент, когда нужно остановить скролл. Прошу помочь с данным моментом.

Comment: Вы хотите вообще запретить дальнейшую прокрутку? Чтобы ни вверх ни вниз?

Comment: вы все правильно поняли

Answer (score 2):

Прокрутку нельзя отменить. Но вы можете сделать это, отменив событие:

[**Демо**](http://rapprogtrain.com/editor/code/2510114229)

```js
function enable() {
  enableScroll();
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Разрешено";
    document.getElementById("status").className = "enabled";
};

function disable() {
  disableScroll();
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Запрещенно";
  document.getElementById("status").className = "disabled";
};


// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

// modern Chrome requires { passive: false } when adding event
var supportsPassive = false;
try {
  window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
    get: function () { supportsPassive = true; } 
  }));
} catch(e) {}

var wheelOpt = supportsPassive ? { passive: false } : false;
var wheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document.createElement('div') ? 'wheel' : 'mousewheel';

// call this to Disable
function disableScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false); // older FF
  window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); // modern desktop
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt); // mobile
  window.addEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

// call this to Enable
function enableScroll() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.removeEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); 
  window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако я все еще могу прокручивать страницу нажав на среднюю кнопку мыши или потянув за scrollbar.

Comment: Вы хоть ссылку на источник кода оставьте.